# Html2Canvas Screenshot clarity

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Using `html2canvas` for taking screenshots. And that screenshot converted to image and attach it with email.

These screenshot includes `highcharts`. Some time x axis and y axis displayed with some shadow effect. How can I avoid it?

```
var tempcanvas=document.createElement('canvas');
tempcanvas.width=2000;
tempcanvas.height=980;
var context=tempcanvas.getContext('2d');
context.imageSmoothingQuality = "High";

context.drawImage(canvas,0,0,1000,750);
var link=tempcanvas.toDataURL('image/png',1);
$scope.alert.message = link;

var blobBin = atob(link.split(',')[1]);
var array = [];
for(var i = 0; i < blobBin.length; i++) {
    array.push(blobBin.charCodeAt(i));
}
$scope.file=new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {type: 'image/png'});
```

[image]

Comment: I ran into a similar issue lately and playing around with the configurations solved it. Try 'tainting', 'imageTimeout' (this one solved for me) and 'async' (this might slow things down a bit).

Comment: @ Andrew Adam Please explain it in detail

Comment: Try to set tainting to true/false, then try to add some imageTimeout and also try to set async to true/false. I spent an hour with different combinations of these configurations and after setting imageTimeout to 100ms it worked. If I recall correctly tainting was also set to true.

Comment: @ Andrew Adam do you have any code snippet?

Comment: have you suceeded? I tried to give a detailed answer with some code snippet as well

Answer (score 2):

May this helps you something

All that is necessary is to set the dpi or scale options when you use html2canvas, and the resulting canvas should have your chosen dpi/scale.

```js
function myRenderFunction(canvas) {
  destination.appendChild(canvas);
}

// Get source element and destination div.
var element = document.getElementById('element');
var destination = document.getElementById('destination');

// Normal html2canvas rendering.
html2canvas(element, {
    onrendered: myRenderFunction
});

// With dpi: 144 (scale: 1.5).
html2canvas(element, {
  dpi: 144,
    onrendered: myRenderFunction
});

// With scale: 2 (dpi: 192).
html2canvas(element, {
  scale: 2,
    onrendered: myRenderFunction
});
```

Answer (score 0):

let me try to assess my comments and also suggest some code:

When I ran into this issue what solved for me is when I started playing around the options of html2canvas. [Here](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/configuration) you can find the available options. When you simply want to call the function you use `html2canvas(element, options)`. Just as emran suggested in their answer, you can pass an object as the second argument to the `html2canvas` function which can contain canvas creation options. Try passing the following:

```
var options = {
  async : false, // setting it to false may slow the generation a bit down
  allowTaint : false, // I am not sure whether it helped or not but I remember setting it
  imageTimeout : 100, // this further delays loading, however this solved a similar issue for me
  foreignObjectRendering : true // it depends on the browser used whether it is allowed or not
}
```

Then you can call your html2canvas function similarly to what emran suggested, however, `onrendered` is no longer necessary since newer versions of html2canvas work with `.then()`

```
var element = document.getElementById('element');
var destination = document.getElementById('destination');

html2canvas(element, options).then(function(canvas) {
    destination.appendChild(canvas);
});
```

Please note that there are several other interesting options at that page that might be useful for you. I can also suggest [this article](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/415/how-to-create-a-screenshot-of-your-website-with-javascript-using-html2canvas) on the topic, this [explanation of the options](http://definitelytyped.org/docs/html2canvas--html2canvas/interfaces/html2canvas.html2canvasoptions.html) and [this library](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf) that combines html2canvas and jsPDF for a direct HTML to PDF conversion.